# Profile setting to sort answers only by votes

Tags: support, answers, sorting

There is any option in the user profile that allows indicate to the system that, when a question is opened (click on question link), it must present the answers ordered only by votes (regardless of the accepted answer) ?

Comment: Each site will remember what you last ordered answers by and always present them to you in that order; until you change it.

Comment: No, that doesn't exist. There are userscripts which do this.

Comment: See [Modified answer view based only on votes, not accepted status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60777/295232)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: I see only three sort options "active", "oldest" and "votes", I've "votes" selected and still accepted answer appears first.

Comment: @Glorfindel: yes, before to post this question I've been reading several similar ones and I've see that the debate about pinned question is historic. It seems something about personal opinions, for this reason I ask about an existing profile flag. (my personal opinion is that the problem with the pinned accepted answer is going to worst)

Answer (score 3):

It's pointless to have this in the profile, since each site "remembers" the last sort you've used, for good, using server side storage attached to your account. (Not a cookie, i.e. cross platform.)

This means that once you sort answers by "votes" it will always sort by votes, unless you choose to sort by something else.

The fact accepted answer is on top regardless of its score (unless posted by question author) is by design, and can't be changed.

If you want it changed, you can start a new [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) question here.